# Permutation to find the best teams possible

Tags: excel, permutation, vba

I'm trying to ask this a different way to get some responses. I've been looking into permutations to find the best value for a team except I can't seem to find any material that gives me a clear understanding of what I need to do.. beginner at creating permutation tables in excel.

what I'm looking to accomplish. I want to get the top 100 permutations (or more if possible) of the possible fantasy football teams.

I'm not quite sure how to set this up since I will need each permutation to include each position as follows QB, RB, RB, WR, WR, TE (6 starters). And since there are different number of players available for each position I'm not sure how to put all of this together or what the best method would be and so I've asked for help!

what I want the outcome to be.

```
Position QB   RB   RB   WR   WR    TE   Total
Fantasy 350  110 115  220  120   125   1040
```

and have the above format continue throughout the permutations figuring out the best possible team.

Players would come from different columns like below:

```
qb               rb
peyton 350   jamaal 235
drew   345
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have found a macro that will give me just the possible position outcome (QB, RB, WR etc) but I can't seem to figure out how to combine the points to the positions and show all permutations for each player at their respective positions.

Thanks again.

Comment: Anybody have any sort of ideas or links where to research?

Comment: I am not sure what you seek. If the player column pairs are in descending order by player score, picking the top player from each column pair will give you the highest possible total. I do not see what permutations have to do with what you request.

Comment: In fantasy football there's usually a maximum number of points you are allowed to use (similar to a salary cap) so you can't pick the best players at every position. Without some idea as to how the user would define a "top permutation", it's going to be difficult to answer this question

Comment: I guess you can ignore the "top Permuation" request.. I could eventually do a look up table off of the permuations for that. But what I guess I'm wanting is every possible draft results possible for my six starters.. if thats possible. 

would it be easier to assume the six starters as rounds? 1-6

so, in the end I would have a table with every combo. like if you take QB peyton manning first pick 350 points and then second pick rb.. second permutation took a RB first pick for 240 points and then a QB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct site for algorithms.  It specialises in help with programming.  However, I will try to get you started.  Please treat each step below as a separate task.  Create a macro that will perform task 1.  When that works, update it to create a macro that performs tasks 1 and 2.  I have tried to define each step so it is a single issue for which you can search for an answer if necessary.  For example, for the first step, searching Stackoverflow for “[excel-vba] Find last column” will give relevant questions and answers that show the most common techniques for this task.

I assume you have a worksheet containing the players per position.  Something like this:

```
   A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       ...
1  QB              RB              RB              WR              ...
2  Albert  100     Bernard 150     Charles 200     David   150
3  Eric    250     Fred    125     George  175     Ian     215
4      :               :                :              :               :                :              :                :
```

You say you currently have six starters.  Does that mean that you will add more players once you understand the problem?  Either way the first task is to identify the number of positions.

With six positions, the last value in row 1 will be in column 11 and the last column with values will be 12.  With a different number of positions, these values will be N and N+1 where N+1 is even and the number of positions is (N+1)/2.

You say there will be a variable number of players per position.  Task 2 is to identify and record the number of players per position.  Searching for “[excel-vba] Find last row” will give a variety of techniques.

I would create a dynamic array, something like:

```
Dim RowPlayerMax() As Long
ReDim RowPlayerMax(1 to NumPositions)
```

I would then loop for each position and record the last row for column `PositionNum*2` in `RowPlayerMax(PositionNum)`.

You will note that I am not showing you the code for that loop.  This is a site where programmers help each other develop.  I am showing you how to break your requirement into small steps.  If I showed you the VBA as well, I would not be helping you develop.  You need to understand the VBA for each step and it will be better for your development if you discover that VBA for yourself.

You need to load the players per position data to memory for fast access.  I would load all this data to a `Variant` which will create a two-dimensional array.  Columns 1, 3, 5 and so on of row 1 will contain the Position names.  Row 2 will contain the first set of player names and points.  Array `RowPlayerMax` will identify the last row for each position.

I think the next step is to decide the sequence in which you wish to generate permutations.  First the easiest sequence.

You already have the array `RowPlayerMax`.  You need another array of the same size: `RowPlayerCrnt`.  You have already initialised `RowPlayerMax`.  You initialise `RowPlayerCrnt` to the number of the first data row in the Player Per Position table which is 2.  Making up some values for the `RowPlayerMax` array, you have:

```
Element           1    2     3    4     5    6
RowPlayerMax     20    5    12    3    15    9
RowPlayerCrnt     2    2     2    2     2    2
```

You then drop into a `Do While True` loop.

The first task within the `Do` loop is to record the permutation defined by `RowPlayerCrnt`.  With my example data this is Albert, Bernard, Charles, David, etc. with a total of 100 + 150 + 200 + 100 ... .

The second task within the `Do` loop is to generate the next permutation.  You need a `For` loop running from 1 to `NumPositions` or in the opposite direction.  I will go from 1 to `NumPositions`.

You look at each position and check its current value against the maximum.  If the current value for a position is less than the maximum value, you step it by one and exit the `For` loop.  If the current value is equal to the maximum value, you set it to the first data row and continue with the `For` loop.  If you exit the `For` loop without stepping a current value, you have generated every permutation.

Consider what this means. The first permutation was `2-2-2-2-2-2`.  On the first loop, the current value for position 1 (2) is checked against it maximum (20).  Since 2 is less than 20, one is added to 2.  The second permutation is `3-2-2-2-2-2`.  The third permutation is `4-2-2-2-2-2` and so on until `20-2-2-2-2-2`.

With `20-2-2-2-2-2`, the current value for position 1 is equal to its maximum so it is set to 2 and the loop continues to consider position 2.  The current value for position 2 is below its maximum so one is added to it.  This gives the next permutation as `2-3-2-2-2-2`.

This will continue until the permutation is `20-5-12-3-15-9`.  It is not possible to increase any of these current values so all permutations have been generated.

You may need to work through this on paper.  Once you have grasped what is happening, you will see this is a very easy way of generating every permutation.

If you are happy with this sequence of permutations, there is little more to do.  You need to extract the information from the Player per Position table and store it in your Permutations table.  Barrowc says there may be a maximum value for the total.  If this is correct, you need to discard some permutations.

Another possible problem is if the same player can play in more than one position.  Player John might be able to appear in either position 1 or position 2 but permutations where John appears in both positions would have to be discarded.

If you intend to generate every possible permutation and then sort them by total, say, the generation sequence does not matter.  However, if you want to generate the top 100 or 200, the sequence does matter.  In this situation, you would probably sort the players for each position and seek permutations:

```
2-2-2-2-2-2
2-2-2-2-2-3
2-2-2-2-3-2
2-2-2-3-2-2
2-2-3-2-2-2
2-3-2-2-2-2
3-2-2-2-2-2
2-2-2-2-2-4
2-2-2-2-4-2
2-2-2-2-4-3
and so on.
```

Before adding the explanation for this sequence, I saw your comment saying you would be happy with every permutation.  I have probably given you enough to think about anyway.

**Edit: Additional advice and code**

Search the web for "Excel VBA Tutorial".  There are many to choose from so try a few and complete one that matches your learning style. I prefer books. I visited a good library and borrowed a few Excel VBA Primers, tried them at home then bought the one I preferred. I cannot make a recommendation because it would match my learning style and yours is probably different.

It would complete my answer to include the code so I have done so.  I have created a macro to perform step 1 then a second macro to perform steps 1, 2 and 3 and so on which is the approach I would recommend to any newbie.  I use the same technique when I am not sure how to achieve the result I seek.  Note the variable names are not exactly the same as in the explanation above.  As I created entire macros, rather than isolated pieces of code, I felt my original names were not quite right.

I have created a workbook with two worksheets: PlayerPerPosition and Permutations.  Change the `With Worksheets("xxx")` statements if you do not like my names.  I have generated some data for PlayerPerPosition whch I believe is an adequate representation of your data:

[image: Example Player Per Position worksheet]

Macro `Test1` determines the number of columns and outputs the result to the Immediate Window using `Debug.Print`.  The Immediate Window should be on the right at the bottom when you open the Visual Basic Editor.  If it is missing, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.  This macro demonstrates two techniques.  I have included comments explaining what I am doing but I do not explain the VBA.  Once you know a VBA statement exists it is usually easy to look it up and find a complete description with examples.  Ask if necessary but the more you can discover for yourself, the faster you will develop your skills.

Macro `Test2` determines and stores the maximum row for each position.  It then loads the entire worksheet as an array.  With both `Test1` and `Test2`, I have used `Debug.Print` to output results.  If I was coding the generation of these permutations for myself I would have coded the macro in one go because I am totally comfortable with the technique.  However I would still have included all the `Debug.Print` stattements.  A simple typo. in steps 1 or 2 could result in subtle errors which could cause total failure in a later step.  Checking each step before advancing to the next avoids such problems.

Macro `Test3` outputs the permutations in the style 2-2-2-2-2-2, 3-2-2-2-2-2, etc.  With my sample data, there are 62,208 permutations which took seven seconds to generate on my laptop.  There is no progress indicator. I would use a form to indicate progress but I thought there were enough ideas in these macros without introducing forms.

Macro `Test4` outputs the actual permutations which took eighteen seconds to generate on my laptop.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test1()

  ' * Task 1 is to discover the number of columns in worksheet
  '   PlayerPerPosition. I demonstrate two techniques.
  ' * Technique 1 which uses the VBA equivalent of Ctrl+Left is
  '   the most popular technique judging from how often it is used
  '   in answers on this site.  However, like all other techniques,
  '   it does not work in every situation.
  ' * The Find method is the most widely applicable technique although,
  '   as the second example shows, you must be careful how you search.

  Dim ColPppMax As Long

  With Worksheets("PlayerPerPosition")

    ' Use VBA equivalenent of Ctrl+Left to find last value in row 1
    ColPppMax = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' Maximum used column is one more than last column with a value in header row
    ColPppMax = ColPppMax + 1
    Debug.Print ColPppMax

    ' Use Find to find last column
    ' Note I am searching by columns
    ColPppMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    Debug.Print ColPppMax

    ' See what happens if I search by rows
    ColPppMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Column
    Debug.Print ColPppMax

  End With

End Sub
Sub Test2()

  ' * Task 2 is save the number of rows per position in worksheet
  '   PlayerPerPosition.  I use the VBA equivalement of Ctrl+Up.
  ' * Task 3 is to load the whole of worksheet PlayerPerPosition to
  '   an array.  For this I need to know the maximum used row for
  '   any position.

  Dim ColPppCrnt As Long
  Dim ColPppMax As Long
  Dim NumPosns As Long
  Dim PosnNumCrnt As Long
  Dim PppTable As Variant
  Dim RowPppMax() As Long
  Dim RowPppCrnt As Long
  Dim RowPppMaxMax As Long

  With Worksheets("PlayerPerPosition")

    ColPppMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    NumPosns = ColPppMax / 2       ' I ought to check there are an even number of columns

    ReDim RowPppMax(1 To NumPosns)

    RowPppMaxMax = 0
    PosnNumCrnt = 1
    For ColPppCrnt = 2 To ColPppMax Step 2
      RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt) = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColPppCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
      If RowPppMaxMax < RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt) Then
        ' If this position has more rows than any previous position, record new maximum row
        RowPppMaxMax = RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt)
      End If
      PosnNumCrnt = PosnNumCrnt + 1
    Next

    'Output maximum row for each column
    Debug.Print "Position ";
    For PosnNumCrnt = 1 To NumPosns
      Debug.Print Right("   " & PosnNumCrnt, 3);
    Next
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print " Max Row ";
    For PosnNumCrnt = 1 To NumPosns
      Debug.Print Right("   " & RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt), 3);
    Next
    Debug.Print

    ' Load worksheet to variant as two-dimensional array
    PppTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowPppMaxMax, ColPppMax)).Value

  End With

  ' Display Players Per Position table
  For RowPppCrnt = 1 To RowPppMaxMax
    For ColPppCrnt = 1 To ColPppMax Step 2
      ' Assume maximum of six characters per player name and
      ' maximum of 9999 for number of points
      Debug.Print Left(PppTable(RowPppCrnt, ColPppCrnt) & Space(6), 6) & " " & _
                  Right("   " & PppTable(RowPppCrnt, ColPppCrnt + 1), 3) & " ";
    Next
    Debug.Print
  Next

End Sub
Sub Test3()

  ' This macro generates the indices into the Ppp Table from which the
  ' actual permutations will be generated.

  ' If you have multi-row headers, using constants makes the code easy to change.
  Const RowPppDataFirst As Long = 2

  Dim ColPppCrnt As Long
  Dim ColPppMax As Long
  Dim GenerationFinished As Boolean
  Dim NumPosns As Long
  Dim PermStr As String
  Dim PosnNumCrnt As Long
  Dim PppTable As Variant
  Dim RowPermCrnt As Long
  Dim RowPppCrnt() As Long
  Dim RowPppMax() As Long
  Dim RowPppMaxMax As Long
  Dim TimeStart As Single

  TimeStart = Timer   ' Seconds since midnight

  ' Stops screen flash and speeds up macro when writing to worksheet
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Worksheets("PlayerPerPosition")

    ColPppMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    NumPosns = ColPppMax / 2       ' I ought to check there are an even number of columns

    ReDim RowPppMax(1 To NumPosns)

    RowPppMaxMax = 0
    PosnNumCrnt = 1
    For ColPppCrnt = 2 To ColPppMax Step 2
      RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt) = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColPppCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
      If RowPppMaxMax < RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt) Then
        ' If this position has more rows than any previous position, record new maximum row
        RowPppMaxMax = RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt)
      End If
      PosnNumCrnt = PosnNumCrnt + 1
    Next

    PppTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowPppMaxMax, ColPppMax)).Value

  End With

   ' Initialise current row table
  ReDim RowPppCrnt(1 To NumPosns)
  For PosnNumCrnt = 1 To NumPosns
    RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) = RowPppDataFirst
  Next

  RowPermCrnt = 1

  With Worksheets("Permutations")

    Do While True

      ' Output current permutation
      PermStr = RowPppCrnt(1)
      For PosnNumCrnt = 2 To NumPosns
        PermStr = PermStr & "-" & RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt)
      Next
      .Cells(RowPermCrnt, 1).Value = PermStr
      RowPermCrnt = RowPermCrnt + 1

      ' Generate next permulation index
      GenerationFinished = True     ' Assume finishe until find otherwise
      For PosnNumCrnt = 1 To NumPosns
        If RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) < RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt) Then
          RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) = RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) + 1
          GenerationFinished = False
          Exit For
        End If
        RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) = RowPppDataFirst
      Next
      If GenerationFinished Then
        Exit Do
      End If

   Loop

  End With

  Debug.Print "Duration " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "##0.00")

End Sub
Sub Test4()

  ' This macro generates actual permutations.

  Const RowPppPosnName As Long = 1
  Const RowPppDataFirst As Long = 2

  Dim ColPppCrnt As Long
  Dim ColPppMax As Long
  Dim GenerationFinished As Boolean
  Dim NumPosns As Long
  Dim PointsTotal As Long
  Dim PosnNumCrnt As Long
  Dim PppTable As Variant
  Dim RowPermCrnt As Long
  Dim RowPppCrnt() As Long
  Dim RowPppMax() As Long
  Dim RowPppMaxMax As Long
  Dim TimeStart As Single

  TimeStart = Timer   ' Seconds since midnight

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Worksheets("PlayerPerPosition")

    ColPppMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    NumPosns = ColPppMax / 2       ' I ought to check there are an even number of columns

    ReDim RowPppMax(1 To NumPosns)

    RowPppMaxMax = 0
    PosnNumCrnt = 1
    For ColPppCrnt = 2 To ColPppMax Step 2
      RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt) = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColPppCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
      If RowPppMaxMax < RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt) Then
        ' If this position has more rows than any previous position, record new maximum row
        RowPppMaxMax = RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt)
      End If
      PosnNumCrnt = PosnNumCrnt + 1
    Next

    PppTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowPppMaxMax, ColPppMax)).Value

  End With

   ' Initialise current row table
  ReDim RowPppCrnt(1 To NumPosns)
  For PosnNumCrnt = 1 To NumPosns
    RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) = RowPppDataFirst
  Next

  With Worksheets("Permutations")

    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete     ' Delete any previous output

    ' Generate header row
    RowPermCrnt = 1
    PosnNumCrnt = 1   ' Uses as column number for Permutations worksheets
    For ColPppCrnt = 1 To ColPppMax Step 2
      .Cells(RowPermCrnt, PosnNumCrnt).Value = PppTable(RowPppPosnName, ColPppCrnt)
      PosnNumCrnt = PosnNumCrnt + 1
    Next
    With .Cells(RowPermCrnt, NumPosns + 1)
      .Value = "Total"
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, NumPosns + 1)).Font.Bold = True

    RowPermCrnt = RowPermCrnt + 1

    Do While True

      ' Output current permutation
      PointsTotal = 0
      ColPppCrnt = 1
      For PosnNumCrnt = 1 To NumPosns
        .Cells(RowPermCrnt, PosnNumCrnt).Value = PppTable(RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt), ColPppCrnt)
        ColPppCrnt = ColPppCrnt + 1
        PointsTotal = PointsTotal + PppTable(RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt), ColPppCrnt)
        ColPppCrnt = ColPppCrnt + 1
      Next
      .Cells(RowPermCrnt, NumPosns + 1).Value = PointsTotal
      RowPermCrnt = RowPermCrnt + 1

      ' Generate next permulation index
      GenerationFinished = True     ' Assume finishe until find otherwise
      For PosnNumCrnt = 1 To NumPosns
        If RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) < RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt) Then
          RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) = RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) + 1
          GenerationFinished = False
          Exit For
        End If
        RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt) = RowPppDataFirst
      Next
      If GenerationFinished Then
        Exit Do
      End If

   Loop

  End With

  Debug.Print "Duration " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "##0.00")

End Sub
```

Comment: This is Awesome, Tony! I'm a beginner to vba but I have a basic knowledge of loops and simple items, but this problem seemed to just overwhelm me on where to start and how to get to the finish. I thank you for the effort you have put into this answer and this will surely get me going, thank you for the explanations on each step it will help pull the ideas together for me.

Comment: On a side note. My background really isn't in coding but I have always been interested and have been trying to expand my knowledge on the subtject. With that said, do you happen to know of any websites or useful materials that you have discovered as useful learning tools or examples?

Comment: @ExcelNoobie25 I have added a new section which I hope is helpful.

Comment: This is Awesome!.. I truly have a long way to go. Thanks for all of your help. @Tony

Comment: @ExcelNoobie25. user3879000 makes some excellent points. My routine generates every possible permutation in a sequence that is convenient for the algorithm. At the end of my first section, I discuss discarding unwanted permutations but my code does not use any of these techniques. My code does not allow for the same player being available for multiple positions. I know little of American football but there are a number of changes I could make that would eliminate some, perhaps all, of the problems mentioned. Would this be helpful or have I given you enough to think about?

Comment: you have given me way more than enough and I thank you for your efforts. I have been digging through your code and trying to learn the process, but if you don't mind showing/explaining the process to improve it would be awesome. Also, do you know if you can take the positions from 4 columns and do the 6 position permutation off of that?

Comment: @ExcelNoobie25  I have responded to your question and have added the enhanced macro I offered as a new answer because I have exceeeded the 30,000 character limit for an answer and I do not wish to delete any of the existing macros.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple version of this last year.
If you run a combination of standard lineups (1QB, 2RB, 3WR, 1TE), you get 420 combinations after your remove repeats.

These combinations are rigid in that they won't "adjust" to a live draft. I used ADP for who I expected to be available at a certain draft position.  Again, it's rigid in that it doesn't adjust for unexpected picks when your leaguemates reach for picks ahead of ADP.

Let's say I'm picking 9th in a 10 team league.  I manually enter values for each position at picks 1.9, 2.2, 3.9, 4.2, etc That sounds tedious, but you will start to see the patterns and it'll take about an hour to trudge through.  Then, you can just sum the column.

I don't understand the jargon that you guys are throwing around.  But if you can make this adjust to a live draft, you will destroy any casual league.  In other words, you are REALLY on to something (I suspect this is how Draft Dominator apps probably work).

At minimum, you're going to learn something from your efforts.  For example, most of the best combinations in my spreadsheet told me to reach to pick Antonio Brown in the 5th, 1-2 rounds before his ADP.  Man if you get 1 player like that, it will be worth your time and effort.

Comment: How did you do your combinations. The one Tony went through has been a great start but there have been two draw backs I have noticed and I'm trying to learn the code and how to adjust it, but the first problem I've run into is that since the columns are the positions I can't get a permutation with two running backs in the same line if they are in the same column. The second, I have cut my players down a ton but excel seems to run out of rows when it tried to cycle through all of the permutations.

Comment: It sounds like you have completed what my main goal was.. I'm looking to create something along the same lines but I'm still new to excel vba and lack the know-how to quickly throw something like this together. @user3879000

Comment: I'm still wracking my brain with how I exactly pulled it off. Start with the same concept as how many different combinations of the letters D,O,G can I make?  Except I used Q,R,R,W,W,W,T.  IIRC something like 4 or 5 thousand combinations came up.  But since each W isn't unique within the same round, you then delete all the repeats (which I also forget how to do, giving you perspective on what I noob I am).  I ended up with 420 possible outcomes for the first 7 rounds.

Comment: This is way simpler than what you guys are doing but this is how I'm gonna start.  Download is in this link... http://www.ne.jp/asahi/math.edu/ami/myprog/jk_eng.htm

Comment: I ran my data for PPR scoring. The 2 players that stand out are Cordarelle Patterson and Joique Bell.  The guy that stood out last yr in this data was Antonio Brown, so I'm hoping to have similar luck.  Draftmas is today for me.  Wish me luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2 - Response and more code**

**Response**

"Also, do you know if you can take the positions from 4 columns and do the 6 position permutation off of that?"  Yes, but I do not think it is worth it.

I assume you want this because a player can be placed in either of the RB and WR positions. (1) I have allowed for that in a different way which I believe offers more flexibility. (2) This requirement would add a step for every position of every permutation.

If you disagree, this is how you achieve the effect you ask about.  Currently, the macro has the following:

```
Position    QB     RB     RB     WR     WR     TE
Column      1      2      3      4      5      6
PppTable

Position    QB     RB     RB     WR     WR     TE
Column      1      2      3      4      5      6
RowPppCrnt  a      b      c      d      e      f
```

Array `RowPppCrnt` identifies which rows to select from array `PppTable`.  a, b, c, d, e and f are row numbers within `PppTable` and the column numbers within `RowPppCrnt` match the column numbers within `PppTable`.

Below, `PppTable` only has 4 columns while `RowPppCrnt` still have 6 entries.  The new array, `SwitchCol`, relates columns in `RowPppCrnt` to columns in `PppTable`.  For example, for column 6 in `RowPppCrnt`, column 6 in `SwitchCol` says go to column 4 in `PppTable`.

```
Position    QB     RB     WR     TE
Column      1      2      3      4
PppTable

Position    QB     RB     RB     WR     WR     TE
Column      1      2      3      4      5      6
SwitchCol   1      2      2      3      3      4
RowPppCrnt  a      b      c      d      e      f
```

**More code**

In macro `Test2`, I introduced the facility to load a range to an array giving faster access.  The opposite is also possible.  For macro `Test5`, I have added a two-dimension array, `PermTable`, with 200 rows in which I accumulate the best 200 permutations.

I have introduced a new constant `Const PointsTotalMaxPermitted As Long = 1000`.  Permutations with a points value above this maximum are rejected.  If you do not want this facility, replace 1000 with some impossibly high value.  Otherwise, replace 1000 with whatever limit is appropriate.

I have introduced a check for the same player being in more than one position.  For my test data, I made the two RB columns and the two WR columns the same.  This is how I handed the requirement behind your question. The disadvantage of this approach is the duplication of data.  The advantages are it does not require extra code and it allows for players who can play in more than one position.

If a permutation passes both the above tests, it is considered for addition to PermTable.  If the permutation is one of the first 200, it is always added.  If it is not within the first 200 and its points value is more then the points value of the lowest value, existing permutation, the old permutation is overwritten by the new.

Only when all permutations have been considered is `PermTable` written to the worksheet.  Macro `Test5` is substantially faster than `Test4` because it is writing very little data to the worksheet.  `Test4` handles 62,208 permultations in 18 seconds.  `Test5` handles 1,080,000 permutations in 4 seconds.

In the code below, I have retained my diagnostic code but have commented it out.  If you wanted to try that code, you will have to add the three worksheets that it uses.

```
Sub Test5()

  ' This macro saves the 200 permulations with the highest permitted totals.

  Const RowPppPosnName As Long = 1
  Const RowPppDataFirst As Long = 2
  Const PointsTotalMaxPermitted As Long = 1000

  Dim ColPppCrnt As Long
  Dim ColPppMax As Long
  Dim GenerationFinished As Boolean
  Dim NumPermsGenerated As Long
  Dim NumPosns As Long
  Dim PermCrnt() As Variant
  Dim PermCrntIsValid As Boolean
  Dim PermTable() As Variant
  Dim PointsTotalCrnt As Long
  Dim PointsTotalLowest As Long
  Dim PosnNumCrnt1 As Long
  Dim PosnNumCrnt2 As Long
  Dim PppTable As Variant
  'Dim RowNotTop200Crnt As Long
  Dim RowPermCrnt As Long
  Dim RowPermCrntMax As Long
  Dim RowPermLowestTotal As Long
  Dim RowPppCrnt() As Long
  Dim RowPppMax() As Long
  Dim RowPppMaxMax As Long
  'Dim RowRepeatCrnt As Long
  'Dim RowTooHighCrnt As Long
  Dim TimeStart As Single

  TimeStart = Timer   ' Seconds since midnight

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Worksheets("PlayerPerPosition")

    ColPppMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    NumPosns = ColPppMax / 2       ' I ought to check there are an even number of columns

    ReDim RowPppMax(1 To NumPosns)

    RowPppMaxMax = 0
    PosnNumCrnt1 = 1
    For ColPppCrnt = 2 To ColPppMax Step 2
      RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt1) = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColPppCrnt).End(xlUp).Row
      If RowPppMaxMax < RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt1) Then
        ' If this position has more rows than any previous position, record new maximum row
        RowPppMaxMax = RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt1)
      End If
      PosnNumCrnt1 = PosnNumCrnt1 + 1
    Next

    PppTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowPppMaxMax, ColPppMax)).Value

  End With

   ' Initialise current row table
  ReDim RowPppCrnt(1 To NumPosns)
  For PosnNumCrnt1 = 1 To NumPosns
    RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1) = RowPppDataFirst
  Next

  ' Size arrays to hold current permutation prior to validation and
  ' the 200 permutation with the highest permitted totals.
  ' Note with 2D arrays it is conventional for the first dimension to
  ' be for columns and the second dimension to be for rows.  Arrays
  ' holded from ranges or to be loaded to ranges are the other way
  ' round.
  ReDim PermCrnt(1 To NumPosns)
  ReDim PermTable(1 To 200, 1 To NumPosns + 1)     ' Extra column for total

  NumPermsGenerated = 0
  RowPermCrntMax = 0
  'RowTooHighCrnt = 0
  'RowRepeatCrnt = 0
  'RowNotTop200Crnt = 0

  'Worksheets("Too High").Cells.EntireRow.Delete     ' Delete any previous output
  'Worksheets("Repeat").Cells.EntireRow.Delete
  'Worksheets("Not Top 200").Cells.EntireRow.Delete
  'Worksheets("Permutations").Cells.EntireRow.Delete

  Do While True

    ' Generate current permulation from indices
    PermCrntIsValid = True  ' Assume current permutation is valid until find otherwise
    PointsTotalCrnt = 0
    ColPppCrnt = 1
    For PosnNumCrnt1 = 1 To NumPosns
      PermCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1) = PppTable(RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1), ColPppCrnt)
      ColPppCrnt = ColPppCrnt + 1
      PointsTotalCrnt = PointsTotalCrnt + PppTable(RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1), ColPppCrnt)
      ColPppCrnt = ColPppCrnt + 1
    Next
    NumPermsGenerated = NumPermsGenerated + 1

    ' Check points total not higher than maximum
    If PointsTotalCrnt > PointsTotalMaxPermitted Then
      PermCrntIsValid = False
      'RowTooHighCrnt = RowTooHighCrnt + 1
      'If RowTooHighCrnt < 65537 Then
      '  With Worksheets("Too High")
      '    For PosnNumCrnt1 = 1 To NumPosns
      '      .Cells(RowTooHighCrnt, PosnNumCrnt1) = PermCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1)
      '    Next
      '    .Cells(RowTooHighCrnt, NumPosns + 1) = PointsTotalCrnt
      '  End With
      'End If
    End If

    ' Check player not repeated
    If PermCrntIsValid Then
      For PosnNumCrnt1 = 1 To NumPosns - 1
        For PosnNumCrnt2 = PosnNumCrnt1 + 1 To NumPosns
          If PermCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1) = PermCrnt(PosnNumCrnt2) Then
            ' Same player in two positions
            PermCrntIsValid = False
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If Not PermCrntIsValid Then
          'RowRepeatCrnt = RowRepeatCrnt + 1
          'If RowRepeatCrnt < 65537 Then
          '  With Worksheets("Repeat")
          '    For PosnNumCrnt2 = 1 To NumPosns
          '      .Cells(RowRepeatCrnt, PosnNumCrnt2) = PermCrnt(PosnNumCrnt2)
          '    Next
          '    .Cells(RowRepeatCrnt, NumPosns + 1) = PointsTotalCrnt
          '  End With
          'End If
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    End If

    If PermCrntIsValid Then
      If RowPermCrntMax < UBound(PermTable, 1) Then
        ' Permutations table is not full so save current permulation in
        ' next available row.
        RowPermCrntMax = RowPermCrntMax + 1
        For PosnNumCrnt1 = 1 To NumPosns
          PermTable(RowPermCrntMax, PosnNumCrnt1) = PermCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1)
        Next
        PermTable(RowPermCrntMax, NumPosns + 1) = PointsTotalCrnt
        If RowPermCrntMax = 1 Then
          ' This is first permutation to be saved.  Record as lowest
          PointsTotalLowest = PointsTotalCrnt
          RowPermLowestTotal = RowPermCrntMax
        Else
          ' Check for new lowest total
          If PointsTotalLowest > PointsTotalCrnt Then
            PointsTotalLowest = PointsTotalCrnt
            RowPermLowestTotal = RowPermCrntMax
          End If
          If RowPermCrntMax = UBound(PermTable, 1) Then
            ' Have just filled Permutations table
            With Worksheets("Permutations")
             .Range(.Cells(1, 1), _
                    .Cells(UBound(PermTable, 1), NumPosns + 1)).Value = PermTable
            End With
          End If
        End If
      Else
        ' Permutations table is full so only save current permulation
        ' if its points total is greater than lowest in table
        If PointsTotalCrnt > PointsTotalLowest Then
          ' Replace permutation with lowest total with with current permutation
          For PosnNumCrnt1 = 1 To NumPosns
            PermTable(RowPermLowestTotal, PosnNumCrnt1) = PermCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1)
          Next
          PermTable(RowPermLowestTotal, NumPosns + 1) = PointsTotalCrnt
          ' Find new lowest total
          ' Initialise lowest from first row in table then search rest of table
          PointsTotalLowest = PermTable(1, NumPosns + 1)
          RowPermLowestTotal = 1
          For RowPermCrnt = 2 To UBound(PermTable, 1)
            If PointsTotalLowest > PermTable(RowPermCrnt, NumPosns + 1) Then
              PointsTotalLowest = PermTable(RowPermCrnt, NumPosns + 1)
              RowPermLowestTotal = RowPermCrnt
            End If
          Next
        Else
          'RowNotTop200Crnt = RowNotTop200Crnt + 1
          'If RowNotTop200Crnt < 65537 Then
          '  With Worksheets("Not Top 200")
          '    For PosnNumCrnt1 = 1 To NumPosns
          '      .Cells(RowNotTop200Crnt, PosnNumCrnt1) = PermCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1)
          '    Next
          '    .Cells(RowNotTop200Crnt, NumPosns + 1) = PointsTotalCrnt
          '    .Cells(RowNotTop200Crnt, NumPosns + 2) = PermTable(RowPermLowestTotal, NumPosns + 1)
          '  End With
          'End If
        End If  ' Current permutation to replace lowest
      End If  ' Permutation table full
    End If  ' PermCrntIsValid

    ' Generate next permulation index
    GenerationFinished = True     ' Assume finishe until find otherwise
    For PosnNumCrnt1 = 1 To NumPosns
      If RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1) < RowPppMax(PosnNumCrnt1) Then
        RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1) = RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1) + 1
        GenerationFinished = False
        Exit For
      End If
      RowPppCrnt(PosnNumCrnt1) = RowPppDataFirst
    Next
    If GenerationFinished Then
      Exit Do
    End If

  Loop  ' until all permutation have been generated

  With Worksheets("Permutations")

    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete     ' Delete any previous output

    ' Generate header row
    RowPermCrnt = 1
    PosnNumCrnt1 = 1   ' Uses as column number for Permutations worksheets
    For ColPppCrnt = 1 To ColPppMax Step 2
      .Cells(RowPermCrnt, PosnNumCrnt1).Value = PppTable(RowPppPosnName, ColPppCrnt)
      PosnNumCrnt1 = PosnNumCrnt1 + 1
    Next
    With .Cells(RowPermCrnt, NumPosns + 1)
      .Value = "Total"
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, NumPosns + 1)).Font.Bold = True

    RowPermCrnt = RowPermCrnt + 1

     ' Write Permutation table to worksheet
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
           .Cells(UBound(PermTable, 1) + 1, NumPosns + 1)).Value = PermTable

  End With

  Debug.Print "Duration " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "##0.00")
  Debug.Print "Number of permutations generated " & NumPermsGenerated

End Sub
```