# How to find the number of combinations available with conditions

Tags: excel, permutation

This is for a Non-profit Hockey League. We have an excel program that looks through the divisions to make sure we have the best possible combination of teams at each level. For example for 43 teams and 5 divisions the possible combinations are (8,8,9,9,9) and (7,9,9,9,9). We have multiple divisions with different combinations?

@CodeCamper - Here is my datasheet based on 46 teams and 6 divisions I do not have a current formula. We list all of the possible options manually. We do divisions of no less than 6 teams and no more than 9 teams. I am looking for a way to populate this table with the data automatically based on specific conditions. For example the number of teams in total and the number of divisions.

Thank you for your help

| Combination # | Div 1 | Div 2 | Div 3 | Div 4 | Div 5 | Div 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 3 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 8 |
| 4 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 8 |
| 5 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 8 |
| 8 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 8 |
| 9 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 7 |
| 10 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 |
| 11 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 |
| 12 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 7 |
| 13 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
| 14 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 7 |
| 15 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| 16 | 9 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 17 | 9 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 18 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 7 |
| 19 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 |
| 20 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 |
| 21 | 7 | 9 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 22 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 7 |
| 23 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 |
| 24 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 |
| 25 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 9 | 7 | 7 |
| 26 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 9 | 7 |
| 27 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 9 |
| 28 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 9 | 7 |
| 29 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 9 |
| 30 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 9 |
| 31 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 32 | 8 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 33 | 8 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 34 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 7 |
| 35 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 |
| 36 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 |
| 37 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| 38 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| 39 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| 40 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 7 |
| 41 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 7 |
| 42 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 9 |
| 43 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 7 |
| 44 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 7 |
| 45 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 7 |
| 46 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 7 |
| 47 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 7 |
| 48 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 9 |
| 49 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
| 50 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
| 51 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
| 52 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 8 |
| 53 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 8 |
| 54 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 55 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
| 56 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
| 57 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 8 |
| 58 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 8 |
| 59 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 8 |
| 60 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 61 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 |
| 62 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 |
| 63 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 8 |
| 64 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 8 |
| 65 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 8 |
| 66 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 67 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 |
| 68 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 |
| 69 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 8 |
| 70 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 8 |
| 71 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 8 |
| 72 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 |
| 73 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| 74 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| 75 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| 76 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 7 |
| 77 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 7 |
| 78 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 9 |
| 79 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 7 |
| 80 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 7 |
| 81 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 7 |
| 82 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 8 | 7 |
| 83 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 | 7 |
| 84 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 9 |
| 85 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 7 |
| 86 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 7 |
| 87 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 7 |
| 88 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 7 |
| 89 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 7 |
| 90 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 9 |

Comment: What problem are you having using the available permutation/combination functions? If you include a simplified dataset with desired output and your current failed attempt it will make it easier for you to get an answer.

Comment: This may be a start for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24892049/4961700